# How to remove specified IP address from iptables?

Tags: iptables

I can access to my CentOS server from specified IP address, when I am using VPN, everything is OK.

When I am running `iptables-save | grep ip.add.re.ss`

```
-A INPUT -s ip.add.re.ss/32 -j ACCEPT
-A DENYIN -s ip.add.re.ss/32 ! -i lo -j DROP
```

But when deleting rule in chain with that line, outputing line with:

```
iptables -L -n --line | grep "ip.add.re.ss"
```

I get line number, but I am unable to delete that DROP rule:

```
30   ACCEPT     all  --  ip.add.re.ss         0.0.0.0/0
201  DROP       all  --  ip.add.re.ss         0.0.0.0/0
```

With:

```
iptables -D INPUT -s ip.add.re.ss -j DROP
```

I get this as output:

```
Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
```

How can I remove DROP rule from my iptables firewall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the rule isn't in the `INPUT` chain.  If you notice in the output from `iptables-save` it's in the chain `DENYIN`.  Also you're missing the `! -i lo` part of the rule.  To delete it use

```
iptables -D DENYIN -s ip.add.re.ss ! -i lo -j DROP
```

Comment: Guess I have to strengthen my iptables skills :)